# Why is NSDictionary implemented as a class cluster?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, foundation

Class clusters group a number of private concrete subclasses under a public abstract superclass. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) uses `NSNumber` as an example; each of the following convenience constructors return a different, private subclass of `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumber *aChar = [NSNumber numberWithChar:’a’];
NSNumber *anInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSNumber *aFloat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
NSNumber *aDouble = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];
```

The motivation for using a class cluster here is explained in the documentation:

> Because numbers of different types have many features in common (they can be converted from one type to another and can be represented as strings, for example), they could be represented by a single class. However, their storage requirements differ, so it’s inefficient to represent them all by the same class.

Other examples of class clusters include `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, and `NSDictionary`. Based on the above explanation, I understand why `NSString` and `NSData` might be implemented as class clusters. After all, an `NSString` instance's storage requirements might be different based on whether it was initialized with a C string or a `CFString`.

But why `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`? It seems like one should implement both of these classes as wrappers around `CFMutableArray` and `CFMutableDictionary`. After all, an `NSDictionary` could store anything as a key or value; there's no telling what the storage requirements are. So storing a CFDictionary seems to be the way to go.

For example, `NSDictionary` could be implemented as `NSXDictionary` below:

```
// NSXDictionary.m

@interface NSXDictionary ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) CFMutableDictionaryRef dictionary;
@end

@implementation NSXDictionary

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL,
                                                0,
                                                &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    CFRelease(_dictionary);
}

- (NSUInteger)count {
    return CFDictionaryGetCount(self.dictionary);
}

- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey {
    return CFDictionaryGetValue(self.dictionary, (__bridge const void *)(aKey));
}

@end
```

My question is: why is `NSDictionary` implemented as a class cluster? Wouldn't it be simpler to implement it as a concrete class, and have `NSMutableDictionary` subclass it?

Comment: How does your class perform compared with NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary? Perhaps there are performance reasons behind this decision.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary is ["Toll-Free Bridged"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH2) to CFMutableDictionaryRef, therefore you do not need a wrapper at all. Any NSMutableDictionary can be used as CFMutableDictionaryRef and vice versa.

Comment: The better question is `why should you care?`  NSDictionary could vend you NSCFDictionaries, or NSDictionary[I/M] or some proxy, or a tagged pointer that the runtime treats as a dictionary.  It doesn't matter, as long as it walks and talks like a dictionary.  Implementing the collections as class clusters guarantees long-term API integrity so that when something better comes along, they just swap out what they hand you, and you never even notice a thing.

Comment: I believe I understand your point, @CodaFi, but maintaining a public interface on a concrete class also guarantees long-term API integrity. Apple is still free to swap out the implementation. As for why I care: a colleague asked me how `NSDictionary` is implemented. I began explaining class clusters, but then realized I didn't know *why* `NSDictionary` is implemented using a class cluster in the first place.

Comment: If you really want to see one implementation, CoreFoundation is open source.  It won't be canonical, though.  Otherwise, again, you shouldn't know or care.  Relying on implementation details is a sign of weak software.

Comment: I understand that, as a consumer of Apple's API, I shouldn't rely on internal implementation details. But reasoning about *how* something is implemented, and *why* it was implemented in that way, seems like a worthwhile mental exercise to me. That's why I care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many different ways can you construct an NSDictionary?

Several of the ways (initWithContentsOfFile, initWithObjectsAndKeys, etc) are more readily implemented by creating an internally variable-size object, filling it in, and then marking it immutable.

Others (initWithObjects:forKeys:count:, initWithDictionary, init, `@{}`) can be well served by a fixed-size (but still temporarily mutable) object.

Then you have the mutable/immutable variation on top of that.

Not a simple class hierarchy.  And a wrapper class is less desirable than a class hierarchy from the standpoint of performance, space occupied, and number of objects created.

(Plus, of course, the overriding answer:  Because Apple calls the shots and that's what they decided.)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you! I will probably accept this answer, but could you elaborate on "a wrapper class is less desirable than a class hierarchy from the standpoint of...space occupied, and number of objects created"? Namely, how does a class hierarchy create fewer objects?

Comment: @modocache - A wrapper class is a separate object from the object it's wrapping.  A subclass just extends the definition of its superclass -- only one object.

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented as a class cluster because it can return an `NSDictionary` or a `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *dict = [mutableDict copy];
```

Like:

```
NSString/NSMutableString 
NSData/NSMutableData
NSArray/NSMutableArray
```

Also indicated in the Apple Documentation:

[image]

at this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Comment: you are reading the table wrong: NSData is the class-cluster, that serves for the public superclasses. But you answer contain nothing about the implementation of a class cluster.

Comment: User ask WHY Apple decided to implement it as a class cluster, and this is the answer, that is also part (i read now) of the answer of Hot Licks!

Comment: sorry man, but you just haven't understood what a class cluster is.

Comment: but hey: maybe complaining to the moderators will help!

Comment: but hey...maybe you are a frustrated person...my answer is not wrong, but continue to down vote some other answer around the community. Bye.

Comment: It is wrong. it does not complain anything and other classes have mutableCopy/copy messages as-well. you do not cover any of the private class-cluster classes that are essential to understanding clusters. I will down vote bad and incorrect answers. you answer fulfills both.

Comment: Yes, mutableCopy/Copy methods are in all the class above in my answer. Copy is also in other class. Anyway, copy on an NSMutableDictionary, return a NSDictionary class..on an NSDictionary another NSDictionary..a mutableCopy on a NSDictionary an NSMutableDictionary and on an NSMutableDictionary another NSMutableDictionary..so the NSDictionary object return instance with different type. And this is part of class cluster.

Comment: and here you are wrong: there is never a NSMutableDictionary returned, but a __NSDictionaryM. There is never a dictionary returned, but either as NSCFDictionary or a __NSDictionaryI. Thats a class cluster: private and varying subclass objects are returned. What you describe are just convenient methods.

Comment: What the table (you are so proud of linking) describes, is that NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary both are abstract and access NSDictionary case cluster to create the real private subclass instances.